# Assertion failed: Color and depth buffers have mismatched kSurfaceUseResolvedBuffer flag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, depth

I use **Unity 2018.1** and today while play testing I got this error:
***Assertion failed: Color and depth buffers have mismatched kSurfaceUseResolvedBuffer flag*** every frame(must be Update problem)
I tried searching but no luck. I created a 2D project so I don't use any shaders or materials. This is an android project(using unity remote) and I didn't did anything in my script except:

```
void Jump // used this for a button
{
    if(movePlayers.isGrounded) //movePlayers is a script
    {
        Debug.Log("Jumping"); // to check wether player is pressing
        movePlayers.rb.velosity = new Vector2(movePlayers.direction.x * moveSpeed, movePlayers.jumpForce); // to make player jump
    }
    return;// just added this one
}
```

I got the answer it is due to the remote device. It doesn't happen when I export it.

Comment: Possibly a unity issue rather than your code. I get the same error spam on 2018.1.4f1 but only when I have a remote device in the editor. 
There is a similar bug on the bug tracker but for metal https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-metal-cant-set-ksurfaceuseresolvedbuffer-surface-flag-errors-appear-when-cameras-clearing-is-set-to-depth-only maybe check your camera?

Comment: You're right disconnecting my redmi note 5 solves the error but I can't still figure out what was actually the error.

Comment: Whatever thanks! :)

Comment: seems to happen when there is unity remote attached

Comment: problem is, does this mean unity remote does not work with 2018.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly a unity issue rather than your code. I get the same error spam on 2018.1.4f1 but only when I have a remote device in the editor. There is a similar bug on the bug tracker but for metal issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/… maybe check your camera? – Deji 15 mins ago 
THE CREDIT GOES TO **DEJI**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 2017.3 and having the same issue while using "unity Remote 5".

I just unplugged the device, restarted Unity and it was gone.